# Tensorflow with GPU on Google Cloud

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, gcloud, google-cloud-ml-engine

I have a model on Google Machine Learning using tensorflow, and it's ok.
Now I want to do some predicts using the GPU.
I saw this [link](https://cloud.google.com/ml-engine/docs/how-tos/using-gpus), but it tells about trainning with GPU not prediction. There's nothing about GPU in prediction session.

Someone Know if its possible to do prediction using google machine learning engine with GPU? Or if I use the trainning with GPU, my Prediction automatically run with GPU?

I'm using the follow commandline:

```
gcloud ml-engine predict --model ${MODEL_NAME} --json-instances request.json
```

This command works, but It's using CPU.
Additional information: My model is published in us-east1 zone, and my scale is automatically.

Comment: Training and inference are pretty much the same thing from Tensorflow's perspective. There isn't a special training mode --- you just run a slightly different graph. If you can run training, you can run inference on the same machine.

Comment: Thanks Peter, I unsdertood that, but I'm using this follow command:

gcloud ml-engine predict --model ${MODEL_NAME} --json-instances ${MY_JSON}

I want to run the predict with GPU with this command. How can I do that? 
That's my doubt....

Comment: Maybe I am greatly mistaken, but; `gcloud ml-engine predict - run Cloud ML Engine online prediction`. You seem to be running this online. Google uses TPUs (Tensor Processing Unit) in their servers. Not sure if "run with GPU" even makes sense in this case.

Comment: Yes, I'm running online, and I dont know too if it makes sense. Now I'm trainning my model with GPU and I'll try to do the online prediction to figure out if is possible to use GPU.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We support GPU now. Documentation [here](https://cloud.google.com/ai-platform/prediction/docs/machine-types-online-prediction)!

Example:

```
gcloud beta ai-platform versions create version_name \
  --model model_name \
  --origin gs://model-directory-uri \
  --runtime-version 2.1 \
  --python-version 3.7 \
  --framework tensorflow \
  --machine-type n1-standard-4 \
  --accelerator count=1,type=nvidia-tesla-t4 \
  --config config.yaml
```

If you use one of the Compute Engine (N1) machine types for your model version, you can optionally add GPUs to accelerate each prediction node.

- NVIDIA Tesla K80
- NVIDIA Tesla P4
- NVIDIA Tesla P100
- NVIDIA Tesla T4
- NVIDIA Tesla V100

Answer (score 1):

You cannot choose to use the GPU for prediction in ml-engine. It's unclear whether they are using GPUs by default -- I would link to documentation but there is none available.

I am sure, however, that they are not using TPUs. Currently, Google is only using TPUs for internal services; although they have created a TPU cloud exclusively for researchers to experiment with: https://yourstory.com/2017/05/google-cloud-tpus-machine-learning-models-training/

If you want more control over how your prediction is run, for the same price you can configure a Google Compute Engine with a high-powered Tesla K80 GPU. Your Tensorflow model will work there, too, and it is straightforward to set up.

My suggestion would be to make benchmark predictions using your GCE instance and then compare them to the ml-engine. If ml-engine is faster than GCE, then Google is probably using GPUs for prediction. Surely, their goal is to provide GPUs and TPUs as an ml-engine in the future, but demand is overloading the HPC cloud these days.

Comment: thanks man! That is what I'm thinking to do! I read a lot about this theme and sent e-mail to google team too. I will run my tests like you said.

Answer (score 1):

Online predictions on GCP ML Engine use Single core CPUs by default which have high latency. If it suits your requirement, you can use the Quad core CPU which serve predictions faster. For using that, you must specify the type of CPU for predictions which creating a version of your model on ML Engine. Link to the documentation : https://cloud.google.com/ml-engine/docs/tensorflow/online-predict.

Answer (score -2):

This site has some information:

https://cloud.google.com/ml-engine/docs/how-tos/getting-started-training-prediction

However, it is a completely different way to train and predict. They provide the means for training and predictiong on their service infrastructure. You just build the model with your Tensorflow program and then use their hardware with their cloud SDK. So it shouldn't bother you whether it runs on CPU or GPU.

Comment: Yes, That is the link that I put in Answer (specific to the trainning part). In this section there is a how to train with GPU but in the prediction section there's no items about GPU. I'm reading a lot about this, and maybe @Cort3z is right (ml-engine predict run with TPU)